# Undefined Method Formatter for Log4r in RAILS 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, log4r

I am getting this error after upgrading Rails from 3.1.2 to 4.0. When launching my server with  rails s I got stuck with the following error

```
C:/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start': undefined method `formatter' for #<Log4r::Logger:0x26dd908> (NoMethodError)
```

I have been on the Log4r site but haven't got any infor;ation  about a bug when upgrading Rails.

Does anyone have any idea where this bug comes from. Thank you!

Comment: I started working on a rails applications written recently using rails 4.1.7.  I tried to switch to log4r and got the same error.

Comment: Found issue reported on Rails, and closed blaming on log4r not implement standard logger API: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14227

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `formatter` is not defined on `Log4r::Logger`, but on `Log4r::FileOutputter`. Therefore I am surprised that is worked before the Rails update. Perhaps that changed between different versions of Log4r.

Please try the following (with adjusted filenames and patters):

```
require 'log4r'
outputter = Log4r::FileOutputter.new('log4r', filename: 'foobar.log')
outputter.formatter = Log4r::PatternFormatter.new(
  date_pattern: "%FT%T.000Z", pattern: "%d [%l] %m"
)

logger = Log4r::Logger.new('log4r')
logger.outputters = [outputter]
```

Add this code to `config/application.rb` or to a new file like `config/initializers/logger.rb`

Comment: Sorry for barging in on an old question, but I'm somewhat surprised this should work: Rails wants to access `Rails.logger.formatter` and your code doesn't add the formatter property to the logger, only an outputter.

Comment: @ma_il: From the the error description it seems like the implementation has changed between version: In older versions, Rails called `formatter` on the `logger` itself. I newer version it calls `formatter` on `logger.outputer`, perhaps through an delegater in the implementation of `Log4r`. I do not know the root cause of the problem. I saw the question and looked for a likely explanation (the is no `formatter` on `logger`, but on `outputer`) and wrote some code to test that hypotheses. Seems that is was right. If this solution does not fix your problem, I suggest to ask an other question.

Comment: where to write the above settings

Comment: @vishB in `config/application.rb` or a file like `config/initializers/logger.rb`.